# Google Books API book other editions

Tags: google-books

I want to find a book (let's call it A) with a certain ISBN. Search for it with its title, only a book (B) with the same title but different ISBN shows up. I can then find the book (A) I want in the "Other Editions" section in the book details of book (B).

Example:
When I want to find the book "the signal and the noise" with ISBN 9781594204111. I typed in "the signal and the noise" in Google Books search and it returned me with the book with ISBN 9781101595954.

Found someone asked the same question in 2012 but no info on whether the feature has been implemented. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/books-api/VZYH-uoGnQE

The main problem: I want to know all ISBNs of books (of different editions) with the same title. Is it possible to be done with Google Books API?

Comment: And fyi, I am using the Google Books API Library for Java.

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't still support this. A non-commercial solution can be found in librarything's API though:

http://blog.librarything.com/thingology/2006/06/introducing-thingisbn/

It's a free version of what OCLC offers in their paid xISBN service.

And by the way, I've found that many of the ISBN's returned in the Google API refer to out of print editions. Just try linking them by isbn_10 to Amazon....